# Block Requests to URL except Android App or C# Application?

Tags: c#, android

I have developed an Android App and a C# Application which calls a URL (website in PHP) in browser control.

I want to block all requests to that URL except from the APP or Desktop Application, I mean no one can directly open that URL in browser.

I tried http Referrer etc but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try sending headers, and only respond to requests that include the header specified?

Comment: Sending headers is an option but is it possible -  can someone interrupt or check headers through fiddler etc and bypass that?

Comment: I guess they could, but then no method is foolproof. Maybe you could send devie information, and some kind of security key as well? This could be a way of authenticating it, to a greater degree. Of course, nothing is perfect.